# jar file requires xml that isn't included in project

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark

I have a Maven project which uses a local jar file. I've added it to my Referenced Libraries and included it in the pom.xml.

When I run `mvn clean install`, I get an error indicating that certain properties cannot be found.

The problem is that the local jar I use reads properties from a `core-site.xml` file which is usually saved in the `spark.conf` folder.

Is there any way I can bring this XML file into my project so it can be used by my local jar?

Comment: Is this "local jar file" a project of yours? Can you change it's code?

Comment: you can use maven resource plugin to include this xml file, if you can edit the pom file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further investigation I found that the `core-site.xml` was in the wrong folder. When it was moved to the correct folder the issue was resolvd.